# Dynamically embed inline-CSS to head using Prestashop module

Tags: prestashop-1.7

How can I dynamically embed an inline-CSS that was entered via the back office. There're only two register methods available for registering assets in Prestashop.

```
public function hookDisplayHeader()
{
    $this->context->controller->registerJavascript('id', 'path/to/file.js');
    $this->context->controller->registerStylesheet('id', 'path/to/file.css');
}
```

The `registerStylesheet` method has an option called `inline`, but that requires the content to be in an existing file first. While I have the CSS code stored in the configurations.

And trying to `echo` the content in `hookDisplayHeader()` results in it being printed above the `<html>` open tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a TPL file in the hooks directory of your module.

Then get the CSS code value from configurations in hookDisplayHeader() function and pass it to smarty:

```
$custom_css = `GET CUSTOM CSS FROM CONFIG`;
$this->smarty->assign('yourcustomcss', $custom_css);    
return $this->display(__FILE__, 'dummy_file.tpl');
```

Then in the TPL file: dummy_file.tpl

```
{if isset($yourcustomcss)}
    <style>{$yourcustomcss nofilter}</style>
{/if}
```

The TPL file is supposed to be in the following directory:

```
/yourmodule/views/templates/hook/dummy_file.tpl
```

Comment: My mistake was directly `echo`ing the contents of the `.tpl`. Using `return` printed it correctly.